# getting following error while installing ffmpeg-php on PHP v5.4.14 / CentOS 5.9

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg, installation

Having trouble installing ffmpg-php on centos, SSH shows following error after commands:

```
./configure 
make
make install

.....

/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1215: warning: âavcodec_decode_vi deoâ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3895)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function â_php_get_av_frameâ:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1282: warning: âhurry_upâ is depr ecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:1388)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1284: warning: âhurry_upâ is depr ecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:1388)
make: *** [ffmpeg_movie.lo] Error 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
B.

Comment: If I were you I wouldn't bother installing `ffmpeg` 0.6, which is absolutely outdated. `ffmpeg-php` was last updated in 2009. You can [compile the newest FFmpeg yourself](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide) as well.

Comment: Thank you. Will that also work with php 5.4 ?

Comment: It depends on what you're planning to do. Do you need the PHP API? If not, you can run any `ffmpeg` version simply through PHP's `exec()`.

Comment: exec() function is disabled. I was just going to install ffmpeg module for php. Thanks.

Comment: You can also try this: https://github.com/alchemy-fr/PHP-FFmpeg